# How to implement trigger action in bot framework v4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot

In v3, we have provision to provide trigger action buttons.

In v4, how can I implement trigger action buttons . Also, how can I provide suggested ***action*** buttons .

in simple, I want below v3 code functionality in v4. please suggest.

```
bot.dialog('help', function (session, args, next) {
    session.endDialog("message");
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^help$/i, });
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by trigger action buttons? Does [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#suggest-action-using-button) help?

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/2122672/kyle-delaney    , below is the link for V3 and looking for same functionality in v4

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#respond-to-user-input

Comment: The documentation you linked to has nothing to do with buttons. Do you want buttons or do you want to simulate trigger actions?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I want to simulate trigger actions in V4. Looking for guidance/reference. Thanks.

Comment: Why does your question mention buttons?

Comment: Kyle, my question meant when user clicks button, it should trigger dialogue.

Comment: But that's not what trigger actions are. A trigger action is when the user types something like "help" then the help dialog gets triggered. Where would the button be? Are you talking about a card that a user can scroll up and click on at any time and have the bot respond correctly regardless of the dialog stack?

Comment: Kyle, in simple, I would like to implement below code in V#4. Any suggestions ?

Below code is in v#3:

bot.dialog('help', function (session, args, next) {
    session.endDialog("message");
})
.triggerAction({
    matches: /^help$/i,
});

Comment: Stack Overflow comments aren't good for formatting code. Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I have added code snippet in question. please suggest , if you have any idea.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called an **interruption**. You want a bot to respond to a global keyword no matter what dialogs are on the stack. You can follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?tabs=javascript) for detailed instructions on how to do this. The guide uses the [Core Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) sample.

Basically any dialog class that extends the `CancelAndHelpDialog` class from the sample will use an overridden `onContinueDialog` function that calls this `interrupt` function:

```
async interrupt(innerDc) {
    if (innerDc.context.activity.text) {
        const text = innerDc.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();

        switch (text) {
        case 'help':
        case '?':
            const helpMessageText = 'Show help here';
            await innerDc.context.sendActivity(helpMessageText, helpMessageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
        case 'cancel':
        case 'quit':
            const cancelMessageText = 'Cancelling...';
            await innerDc.context.sendActivity(cancelMessageText, cancelMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
            return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
        }
    }
}
```

The function checks if the user entered "help" or "?" or "cancel" or "quit" and responds accordingly. If you don't want to follow the sample you can still call the function from anywhere you have access to a dialog context.